# SQL: where json field in (,..,)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, syntax-error

I've been trying tens of different combinations with no success.
I have a table `policies`, in which one column is `id` and one column is `created_for`, which is itself a json.
The json looks like this: `created_for: {"user_email": "hello@gmail.com", "project_serial": "K8BUADS001="}`.

Now I want to get all `id` in which the `project_serial` is in certain values.

What I tried:

```sql
SELECT p.id 
FROM policies as p 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(created_for, '$.project_serial') IN ('PROJIUHS6W001=', 'U5LQU13BIBN001=')

SELECT p.id 
FROM policies as p 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(created_for, '$.project_serial') IN ("PROJIUHS6W001=', 'U5LQU13BIBN001=")

SELECT p.id 
FROM policies as p 
WHERE created_for->>'$.project_serial' IN ('PROJIUHCHQ62UJ0KSS6W001=', 'PROJPPF4UE5LQU13BIBN001=')

SELECT p.id 
FROM policies as p 
WHERE created_for->>'$.project_serial' IN ("PROJIUHCHQ62UJ0KSS6W001=", "PROJPPF4UE5LQU13BIBN001=")
```

and just any other combination of double/single quotes on every parameter.
All of these give me syntax error, I've been getting a lot of: `syntax error near unexpected token '('`, but also others as I tried many combinations.

Anyone knows what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If you find yourself needing to look inside JSON fields in SQL, it's probably time to define relational schema around those fields and populate at insert/update time. Not _every_ json attribute, mind you; just the ones you'll need to search. Otherwise, not only do you have to parse and look inside the json for the rows you need, but you'll also have to parse the json of **every record in the table**. Additionally, if you have extracted this data at insert/update time you can also have indexes around those fields. _**Without exaggeration, it can be 1000 times faster.**_

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
p.id FROM policies as p WHERE  json_extract(created_for, '$.project_serial') IN 
('PROJIUHS6W001=', 'U5LQU13BIBN001=')
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still got `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: @spagno try to run it on a fresh window...there is not any ('` in the query..  is your json data properly inserted?? in proper json format ??

`created_for: {"user_email": "hello@gmail.com", "project_serial": "K8BUADS001="}`  is not the correct one  it should only be `{"user_email": "hello@gmail.com", "project_serial": "K8BUADS001="}`